# How to open a DB as read only in vba?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to open an access DB in the form of read only using Excel VBA.

This is the code that I have at the moment,

```
        Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
        cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & DBFullName & ";"

        Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
        rs.Open "SELECT DISTINCT A_Name FROM app_tbl ORDER BY A_Name ASC", cn, , , adCmdText
```

How can I open it as read only ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
 cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & DBFullName & ";Mode=Read"
```